# Is there a way to make eclipse show the defined methods in a variables in class without typing a period?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I know when typing something like "this." Eclipse will show a list of all the methods and variables of this but is their a way to show the list without having to enter a period before?
Thanks

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to type `Ctrl` + `Space` or look into the outline view.

Answer (score 0):

No, because without the period it's not clear that you want to access a method or member or other variable. However with `CTRL + Space` of course you will get a selection of possibilities you might want to type (e.g. class names).